# How to install pcntl extension on ubuntu 15

Tags: php, ubuntu, pcntl

I am trying to install pcntl on ubuntu 15 and i get this while trying to get php5 source.

The procedure that I am fallowing is

```
sudo apt-get source php5
cd php5(release version)/ext/pcntl
sudo phpize
sudo ./configure
sudo make
sudo make install
```

But on

```
sudo apt-get source php5
```

I am getting

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
NOTICE: 'php5' packaging is maintained in the 'Git' version control system at:
git://anonscm.debian.org/pkg-php/php.git
WARNING: The following packages cannot be authenticated!
  php5
E: Some packages could not be authenticated
```

Server is ubuntu server 15.04

PHP 5.6.4-4ubuntu6.3 (cli) (built: Sep 29 2015 12:44:47)

Can anyone help me on this?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, try this in terminal first:
    `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/php5-5.6`